# Approximation for $\log_{10}$ around $x = 1$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\log_{10}(x) \approx \frac{x - 1}{x + 1}$$

around $x = 1$ this is a pretty good approximation:

[image: desmos]
(https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y0gamzphtc)

Is this a mere coincidence, or is there some explanation for this (perhaps Taylor?)?

Comment: It is really not such a good approximation. The RHS approximates $\log_{e^2}x$, where $e^2\approx 7.389$ is not even too close to $10$.

Comment: The derivative of $\log_{10}(x)$ at $1$ is $1/\ln(10) \approx 0.434$, while the derivative of $(x-1)/(x+1)$ at $1$ is $1/2 = 0.500$, so the approximate numerical proximity of these slopes may sort of explain this. (It also explains why the red graph is slightly "steeper" at $1$ than the blue graph, which is not clear from the above unless you zoom in.)

Comment: This is not a complete coincidence. A "fairly good" approximation can be explained by the fact that $2/\ln 10$ is around $1$, since the best approximation via rational function (of such form near $x=1$) is $$\frac{2}{\ln 10}\times\frac{x-1}{x+1}.$$ See Padé approximant.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some of the rational approximations in 'Computer Approximations' by Hart, et al. You'll see the form $\log_{10} x \approx z P(z^2)/Q(z^2)$, where $z := (x - 1)/ (x+1)$, with $P$ and $Q$ polynomials. This suggests the significance of the term you're using. On the interval $-1/\sqrt{10} < x < \sqrt{10}$ the best uniform approximation with $P$ and $Q$ first order polynomials has error less than $10^{-5}$.

Answer (score 0):

The approximation is closely related to the Padé approximant (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant)) of $\log_{10}(x)$ as well. One has that the Padé approximant around $x=1$ is

$$ 
\log_{10}(x) = \frac{2(x-1)}{(x+1)\ln(10)} 
$$

So no, it is no coincidence that the approximation works. I missed it, but this is what was already mentioned in the comments by @Marek Kryspin.

Continuing with the Padé-(2,2) approximant, one has the even better approximation

$$ 
log_{10}(x) = \frac{3(x-1)(x+1)}{(x^2+4x+1)\ln(10)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since I only know one logarithm, I shall write that
$$\log_{10}(x)=\frac{1}{\log (10)}\, \log(x)$$ Around $x=1$, we have
$$\log(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,(x-1)^n$$

If you want a good rational approximation, probably the best would be to use the $[n+1,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ (because the first term of the expansion is not a constant.

To make the expressions shorter, let $x=t+1$ and the first $P_n$ will be
$$P_1=\frac{t (t+6)}{4 t+6}\qquad \qquad P_2=\frac{t \left(t^2+21 t+30\right) } {3 \left(3 t^2+12 t+10\right) }$$

For iillustration, using the range in your plot, consider the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_{0.5}^{5.5}\Bigg[ \log_{10}(x)-\frac{P_n}{\log (10)}\Bigg]^2\,dx$$

$$\Phi_1=1.151\times 10^{-2}\qquad \Phi_2=1.615\times 10^{-4}\qquad \Phi_3=2.883\times 10^{-6}$$